# How to view map of the world

Tags: terraria-mobile

Opening map of the world is possible in Terraria PC (by using button on the screen) but I had hard time figuring it out for android version. Today I finally found the map option in the mobile version. It is given in solution below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is'nt a particular button for opening the map.

But map can be opened by pinching 2 fingers(like zooming out the game screen) above the joystick area i.e. top right area of screen

Comment: well you are close, its actually a vertical pench in the center of the screen.